# Start/Stop webkit animations onclick instead of on:hover

Tags: javascript, css, animation, menu, webkit

I'm having some trouble starting the animations when .menu is clicked on rather than it's hovered on. What should go in my function clickeffect to start the animations onclick?

It won't let me post the question so here are some more words.

```js
function showmenu(){
 var menu = document.getElementById('mobile-menu'), maxH="148px";
 if (menu.style.height == maxH){
  menu.style.height = "0px";

 }else{
  menu.style.height = maxH;
 }
}

function clickeffect(){
 var burgermenu = document.getElementByClassName('menu');
}
```

```css
.menu {
 position: relative;
 display:  inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 25px;
}
.menu span {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 top: 12px;
}
.menu span:before, .menu span:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
}
.menu span, .menu span:before, .menu span:after {
 width: 30px;
 height: 6px;
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
}
.menu span:before {
 margin-top: -12px;
}
.menu span:after {
 margin-top: 12px;
}

.menu span {
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s; transition-duration: 0s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.menu:hover span {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.menu span:before {
 -webkit-transition-property: margin, -webkit-transform; transition-property: margin, transform;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s; transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s, 0s; transition-delay: 0.2s, 0s;
}
.menu:hover span:before {
 margin-top: 0;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s; transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
}
.menu span:after {
 -webkit-transition-property: margin, -webkit-transform; transition-property: margin, transform;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s; transition-duration: 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s, 0s; transition-delay: 0.2s, 0s;
}
.menu:hover span:after {
 margin-top: 0;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s; transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
```

```html
<a href="#" id="nav-toggle" class="menu"><span onclick="showmenu('mobile-menu')+clickeffect('nav-toggle')"></span></a>
```

Comment: The question is not clear. The js function showmenu is trying to access element mobile-menu. Where is this element defined? Also why you are passing passing parameters to showmenu and clickeffect when they are never used?

Answer (score 1):

On click, toggle a class on `.menu` like say `active`. Then in your CSS, change `.menu:hover` to `.menu.active`

Comment: <a href="#" id="nav-toggle" class="menu"><span onclick="showmenu('mobile-menu')+menu.active"></span></a> like that?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by 'toggle a class on menu'